# android - softkeyboard keeps hiding after expanding Searchview programmatically (w/ Search Button)

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, searchview

I am using `SearchView` from Support Library in my Appcombat Actionbar.
On emulator it all works as intended. I can open it by clicking the menu item or using the Search Button on the device and the keyboard is shown.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
        if(!MenuItemCompat.isActionViewExpanded(searchItem)) {
            MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchItem);
        } else MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

On Expanding I set a saved text.

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            searchView.onActionViewExpanded(); // to initialize searchview
            searchView.setQuery(searchText, false);
            searchView.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Problem:

On my hardware device (HTC Desire HD, Android 2.3), when I press the device's Search Button the searchview expands and the softkeyboard shows for a part of a second and hides again. Clicking the MenuItem works fine and shows the keyboard as intended. There seems to be a method hiding the keyboard again after focusing the searchview. I already tried several stuff (`setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener` with manually showing softInput) but none seem to work on my device.

I hope someone got a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your searchView has lost focus after setting the searchText.
try adding this before calling requestFocus.

```
searchView.setFocusable(true);
```